# Cannot implicitly convert type List<<anonymous type: ..>> to IEnumerable<Product>

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I am trying the execute linq query `Join` but an Exception has popped up.

This my method:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> TestProducts()
{
    var items = await _context.Products.Join(_context.ProductTypes,
         p => p.ProductId,
         c => c.ProductTypeId,
         (p, c) => new
         {
             productId = p.ProductId,
             number = p.Number,
             amount = p.Amount,
             primeCostEUR = p.PrimeCostEUR,
             nameType = c.NameType

         }).ToListAsync();
    return items;
}
```

This my model:

```
public class Product //: BaseObject
{
    public long ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
    public double PrimeCostEUR { get; set; }

    public long ProductTypeId {  get; set; }
    public ProductType ProductType { get; set; }

    public long ProductParameterId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProductParameter> ProductParameters { get; set; } = 
    new List<ProductParameter>();
}

public class ProductType //: BaseObject
{
    public long ProductTypeId { get; set; }

    public string NameType { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Parameter> Parameters { get; set; }

}
```

This is the error I have encountered:

> Error  CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<.Models.Product>'.

Comment: The error seems self-explanatory. Can you not just select `new Product { }` instead of an anonymous type `new { }`? Oh, wait, you're including `NameType`, which is not a property of `Product`. Basically, since you've defined the method as returning an `IEnumerable<Product>`, then that's what you have to return. So either change the return type or change what you're returning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its seems that your expected return output is combination of both `Product` and `ProductType` model class. So make a DTO (Data Transfer Object) class as follows which will contain all the fields of your output query.

```
public class ProductDto
{
    public long ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
    public double PrimeCostEUR { get; set; }
    public string ProductTypeName { get; set; }
}
```

Now write your controller method as follows where return type of the method is `IEnumerable<ProductDto>`:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ProductDto>> TestProducts()
{
    var items = await _context.Products.Select(p => new ProductDto
         {
             ProductId= p.ProductId,
             Number= p.Number,
             Amount= p.Amount,
             PrimeCostEUR= p.PrimeCostEUR,
             ProductTypeName = p.ProductType.NameType
         }).ToListAsync();
    return items;
}
```

Moreover you don't need explicit LINQ join as you did, you can achieve the same thing using EF projection as I have done with more simplicity.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I’m beginner to .NET. Must have each join query has its own DTO class?

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
 var items = await _context.Products.Join(_context.ProductTypes,
             p => p.ProductId,
             c => c.ProductTypeId,
             (p, c) => new
             {
                 productId = p.ProductId,
                 number = p.Number,
                 amount = p.Amount,
                 primeCostEUR = p.PrimeCostEUR,
                 nameType = c.NameType

             }).ToListAsync();
```

to this:

```
 var items = await _context.Products.Join(_context.ProductTypes,
             p => p.ProductId,
             c => c.ProductTypeId,
             (p, c) => new Product  //as Product not anonymous
             {
                 productId = p.ProductId,
                 number = p.Number,
                 amount = p.Amount,
                 primeCostEUR = p.PrimeCostEUR,
                 nameType = c.NameType

             }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Of course those property names would need to change a little, and `Product` doesn't have a `NameType`...

Comment: well I actually didn't pay attention much to product class ;)

Comment: Yeah, I had a comment that was the same as your answer, but then I noticed that they were including a field from the joined table in the result, so that breaks things. They either need to not include the field or define another type that does include it and return an `IEnumerable` of *that* type.